# Remove metadata from textformat type as HTML in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

```
$mydata= Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Html  | Out-String
```

Here I am trying to copy data from Excel into HTML format. The metadata is not looking good for me. Tried like below as well but no success:

```
$mydata=Get-Clipboard -Format html -TextFormatType Unicodetext |  Out-String
```

Metadata :- Version:1.0 StartHTML:0000000171 EndHTML:0000053849 StartFragment:0000002468 EndFragment:0000053797 SourceURL:file://c:/Testdata\liknkvalidate.xlsx

Comment: "By that time defaultly metadata which is coming and looking not good" - what does that look like?

Comment: Version:1.0 StartHTML:0000000171 EndHTML:0000053849 StartFragment:0000002468 EndFragment:0000053797 SourceURL:file://c:/Testdata\liknkvalidate.xlsx

Comment: @learner - and what do you *want* it to look like? Can you add the source sheet, the current result and the desired result examples into your *original question* rather than as comments...

Comment: Basic examples work, I just tested it. What is the content you're trying to copy @learner?